# Align textView next to another one programatically

Tags: android-layout, textview, android

I am programmatically creating a text view and trying to place another textView right next to the first one. But I am unable to do it.

Here is the code I have written,

```
    //1st textview
     TextView itemText = new TextView(context);
    itemText.setText(mItemText);
    Typeface itemFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/" + "Roboto" + ".ttf");
    itemText.setTypeface(itemFont,Typeface.BOLD);
    itemText.setPadding(0, padding, 0, 0);
    itemText.setId(10);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams itemTextParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    itemTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    itemTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    itemText.setTextSize(font_size);
    itemText.setLayoutParams(itemTextParams);

    //2nd text view
    TextView seperator = new TextView(context);
    seperator.setText(mSeperator);
    seperator.setPadding(0,padding,0,0);
    seperator.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams seperatorParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    seperatorParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    seperatorParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,itemText.getId());
    seperatorParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    seperator.setLayoutParams(seperatorParams);
```

seperatorParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) works, but when I use seperatorParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,itemText.getId()) , the text is not shown.

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong? Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of `itemTextParams` is set to `MATCH_PARENT`, so there's no space to put anything to the right of it. Change it to `WRAP_CONTENT` or define a width value.